# Select2 not displaying the select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have a problem with the Select2 plugin's last version, I don't know why the select box isn't showing up. I'm using Bootstrap 5.1.3, JQuery 3.6.1, Select2 4.1.0rc

**JavaScript:**

```js
const locationSelect = $('#location').select2({
    ajax: {
        delay: 250,
        url: "<?= site_url('admin/select2_get_locations'); ?>",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data.results
            };
        },
    },
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
        return markup;
    },
});
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 mb-4">
    <label for="location">Filtro per località</label>
    <select id="location" name="location" style="width: 100% !important">
        <option value="" selected>Seleziona</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Image:**

How Select2 appears to me.

[image]

I tried to use the stable and RC version, but nothing changed, I'm using its default theme but nothing. Tried to search in the theme if there was a line of code overwriting mine, but nothing was found.

Comment: This looks like a CSS issue. Use the DOM inspector to check that you don't have any rules overriding or interfering with the standard Select2 stylesheet

Comment: I have already tried to inspect the CSS but no rules were overwritten @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Looks like the select2.css has not been loaded.   Can you create a *snippet* in the question that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the ajax options and just have `$('#location').select2();`?

Comment: Something in your CSS (which we can't see) might be interfering. Please see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yuxqv41h/). It's a bare-bones example. Try to scale down - place just this bit of select2 code, include your jQuery JS and select2 CSS and JS, and try it on a blank page, with no extra elements or CSS. Also, use the document inspector in your browser - look for all the `span` elements with the `select2` class, which are immediately beneath your `select#location` element. Once you find them, experiment with CSS rules for width, z-index, height, display, etc.